# sqlite3_exec is there a memory leak?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, sqlite

I'm using SQLite to store my data. I'm writing wrapper class, and I want to know: will be a memory leak if (res != SQLITE_OK) and errorMsg will be displayed to the screen??

So do I need to do free(errorMsg); in the "if" statement? Thanx!

```
-(int) executeQuery: (NSString *) sqlQueryStr
{
char *errorMsg = NULL;
int res = SQLITE_ERROR;

res = sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlQueryStr UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg);

if (res != SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_close(database); 
    NSLog(@"executeQuery Error:  %@", errorMsg);
    database = NULL;
    return res;
}

return res;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the memory managed for arguments passed to \`sqlite3\_exec()\`'s "callback" parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75394713/how-is-the-memory-managed-for-arguments-passed-to-sqlite3-execs-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `sqlite3_free()` to release the error message string, as per [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html):

> To avoid memory leaks, the application
>   should invoke sqlite3_free() on error
>   message strings returned through the
>   5th parameter of of sqlite3_exec()
>   after the error message string is no
>   longer needed.