# How is the memory managed for arguments passed to sqlite3_exec()'s "callback" parameter?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, memory-management, callback

SQLite's [One-Step Query Execution Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) looks like:

```
int sqlite3_exec(sqlite3 *db,                             /* An open database */
                 const char *sql,                         /* SQL to be evaluated */
                 int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),/* Callback function */
                 void *p1,                                /* 1st argument to callback */
                 char **errmsg);                          /* Error msg written here */
```

For the last parameter `errmsg`, the memory management guideline is:

> If the 5th parameter to `sqlite3_exec()` is not `NULL` then any error message is written into memory obtained from `sqlite3_malloc()` and passed back through the 5th parameter. **To avoid memory leaks**, the application should invoke `sqlite3_free()`

However, there is no mention about what has to be done for the `callback()`! It has 3rd and 4th argument passed as `char**`.
**Question**: Who has to memory manage it and should it be freed-up in the same way as above?

**Purpose**:

I am using SQLite in an application which involves lots of data fetching with various `SELECT`s. After few days of run, the RAM usage increases gradually from 50 MB to 150 MB and then to 250 MB. With the "Deleaker" tool most of the major memory allocations are shown in "sqlite3.c" file.

Comment: ChatGPT content is banned on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can just read the [source code to sqlite3_exec](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/37d4ec86bfa78c31732132b7729b8ce0e47da891/src/legacy.c#L65-L121).

For every iteration of the loop, values are retrieved:

```
        if( rc==SQLITE_ROW ){
          azVals = &azCols[nCol];
          for(i=0; i<nCol; i++){
            azVals[i] = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(pStmt, i);
            if( !azVals[i] && sqlite3_column_type(pStmt, i)!=SQLITE_NULL ){
              sqlite3OomFault(db);
              goto exec_out;
            }
          }
          azVals[i] = 0;
        }
```

and after the callback, they are freed:

```
    sqlite3DbFree(db, azCols);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think is there any area of suspicion in "sqlite3.c", which may cause memory leaks apart from these? Note that, I am not using `sqlite3_prepare()` anywhere, just using `sqlite3_execute()` directly.

Comment: The exec function uses prepare internally to get a cursor. Assume that that function does not leak memory.